Text parsing nightname in MS Excel
Background: I was asked to fix a datalist with a long text column which gets significant amount o of new entries added in a daily basis, so I need to automate that.
What: I need to move parts of a text to the start based on a FROM/TO list. The trick is that there could be more than 1 text to be moved, and there some items on the list have characters that overlaps the rows above - check table reference.
Attempt: I thought using reduction function to remove the texts found in the FROM/TO in the end, but in my head the calculation starts by finding the tests in Table Reference and writting them at the start. Tried using FIND for that, but them realised it probably needs to be iterative, meaning, I find the 1st text than I update the original text to remove what I've already found before I search for the next item in "Reference - to compare" table.
Notes:
a) I can add support columns to facilitate the calculation in my spreadsheet.
b) As far as I could check, the maximum is 4 text replaces in a cell, but the vast majority of rows will vary between 1 or 2 replaces.
Test File Available: https://file.io/bdcoaRMhsPvz


It might be easier to do this with VBA instead of formulas

The file link which you have posted shows file deleted, so users have to do write it down manually in order to produce a working solution for your query.

That is weird as I tested the link before posting. Anyhow, I uploaded the file again: https://www.file.io/tJB2/download/tIgVW09KulB0

Never mind, i did manually and posted an answer. And you can download from here

May be there is more compact and elegant way of doing, however, I came up with this following formula, which actually works with the given data in the OP:


• Formula used in cell B4
=LET(
     α, TEXTSPLIT([@original],Reference[to compare]),
     δ, TEXTSPLIT([@original],α,,1),
     φ, TEXTJOIN(" + ",1,XLOOKUP(UNIQUE(δ,1),Reference[to compare],Reference[to replace],""))&" - ",
     IFERROR(TRIM(CONCAT(TOCOL(VSTACK(φ,α),2,1))),[@original]))


Alternatively, can use VLOOKUP() instead of XLOOKUP()
=LET(
     α, TEXTSPLIT([@original],Reference[to compare]),
     δ, TEXTSPLIT([@original],α,,1),
     φ, TEXTJOIN(" + ",1,VLOOKUP(UNIQUE(δ,1),Reference,2,0))&" - ",
     IFERROR(TRIM(CONCAT(TOCOL(VSTACK(φ,α),2,1))),[@original]))


If not using Structured References then once could use the following to spill  using LAMBDA() helper function MAP()
=MAP(List[original], LAMBDA(Σ, LET(
     α, TEXTSPLIT(Σ,Reference[to compare]),
     δ, TEXTSPLIT(Σ,α,,1),
     φ, TEXTJOIN(" + ",1,XLOOKUP(UNIQUE(δ,1),Reference[to compare],Reference[to replace],""))&" - ",
     IFERROR(TRIM(CONCAT(TOCOL(VSTACK(φ,α),2,1))),Σ))))


NOTES: There is typo in the given desired result for cell B6, if i am not mistaken.


Hey Mayukh, just checked your formulas, that is absolutely brilliant, thanks so much.
I see I had the wrong mindset to approach the problem, also I didn't know textsplit accepts an array as parameter and checks every value - thanks again.

@FabricioAntonello glad to know that, No issues at all. Try practice you will learn as well! Yes TEXTSPLIT() if you multiple delimiters then what would you do? Will you not do something like this --> =TEXTSPLIT(A2,{"-","|","~"},,1)

I honestly had never tried multiple delimiters. I think I let the Excel function helper (the pop-up when you click on Fx) deceive me as arrays are not mentioned as a valid parameter for most of the functions, TEXTSPLIT is one of them. But your overall approach was brilliant, I don't think I'd have approached the issue that way. Congrats.

@FabricioAntonello see here there is an example posted by MSFT will help you as well. Thanks again!
